# Spring profile setting in application.properties works as expected in Windows, not in Linux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing a Spring Boot application (Spring Boot 2.7.12, Spring Cloud 2021.0.7). I'm using profile-specific settings in application.properties. When I re-set a property in profile-specific section, it is applied in Windows (Oracle JDK 17), but not in Linux (openjdk 17).

My original `application.properties` looks as follows:

```
spring.application.name=cloud-gateway
spring.config.import=configserver:http://localhost:8888/
#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=testing
spring.config.import=configserver:http://192.168.30.10:8888/
spring.cloud.config.username=service
spring.cloud.config.password=password
```

When I run the compiled Spring Boot jar with `java -jar gateway.jar --spring.profiles.active=testing`, in Windows the config server bootstraps correctly to remote machine. However, in production Linux environment exactly the same command results in error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/cloud-gateway/testing": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

So the profile is set correctly, but the `spring.config.import` is not applied under the testing profile.

I could work around the problem with the following properties file:

```
spring.application.name=cloud-gateway
#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=default
spring.config.import=configserver:http://localhost:8888/
#---
spring.config.activate.on-profile=testing
spring.config.import=configserver:http://192.168.30.10:8888/
spring.cloud.config.username=service
spring.cloud.config.password=password
```

Am I missing something? From the documentation I'd guess that this should work also in the first example as expected also in Linux.

Comment: It's a long shot, but is it possible that Windows line endings may somehow disrupt mutli-profile configuration on linux?

Comment: You can test if you have access to the config server from the Windows Machine please.

Comment: @TomekK this occurred to me also, but no. The line endings are LF and file encoding UTF-8.